# How to access python static method which contain instance members?

Tags: python, static-methods

I try to learn static methods in python. Here is my code-

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 20
        self.lst = []

    @staticmethod
    def addNappend(self, c):
        sum = self.a + self.b + c
        self.lst.append(sum)
        print(self.lst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ABC.addNappend(30)
```

I am getting error to run my code.
[TypeError: addNappend() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c']

What need to changes? Thanks all of u.

Comment: If it's a `@staticmethod`, it shouldn't have the parameter `self`. The parameter `self` refers to the instance that the method is being called on - in the case of a static method, there is no instance, so it shouldn't be present.

Comment: one way I guess is to instantiate ABC() in the staticmethod and then use the instance's attributes.  if you do that, you're better of using @classmethod.

Comment: You do not want static method  here.

Comment: So, how can I access my instance member inside from static member?

Comment: You can not access instance variables from inside a static method. That is the very core part of a static method. They are used for calling the function without needing to instantiate the class. I would suggest you Google "static/class methods and their purpose/limitations"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is clear: the method requires two arguments: an `ABC` object and another value; these are positional arguments.  Since you called this as a *class* method, rather than an *instance* method, you have to explicitly provide the `ABC` object.  At the moment, you have no `self` to alter; what did you expect that call to do?

Instead, instantiate an object and use that:

```
phone_button = ABC()
phone_button.addNappend(30)
```

---

Note that this is not at all related to making this a static method ... which seems to serve no purpose in this class.